# Presto identify unique values

Tags: database, presto

New to `presto`, I have a table with a column contains a lot key value pairs. I can extract each row's keys using `map_keys', but I am wondering is there a function to combine and list all unique keys in one row?

get all the keys

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT MAP_KEYS(col)
FROM tbl
```

what it looks like:

```
_col0
[key1, key2]
[key2, key3]
```

#### desired outputs:

```
_col0
[key1, key2, key3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT k)
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(map_keys(col)) AS t (k)
```